# Difficulty in understanding quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

In quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 1+3i\rangle$, I don't understand how are we saying $1+3i=0$ that is $i=3$ or $10=0$

Comment: One is not saying that, one is saying that two Gaussian integers that differ by a (Gaussian integer) multiple of $1+3i$ are to be considered "the same." Just like in modular arithmetic mod $7$.

Comment: Although actually $10$ and $0$ do differ by a (Gaussian integer) multiple of $1+3i$, so $10=0$ does hold (along with other strange things) in this particular quotient ring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that the elements of $\mathbb Z[i]/\langle 1+3i\rangle$ are *equivalence classes* of Gaussian integers.

When we say $i=3$ in the quotient ring, what we really mean is that $i$ and $3$ are *representatives of the same equivalence class*. To wit, they are related, because $i-3$ is a multiple of $1+3i$, namely $i\cdot (1+3i)=-3+i = i-3$.

Similarly we have $[10]=[0]$ because $10-0 = (1-3i)(1+3i)$.

In order to be fully formal one should perhaps write something like $[i]=[3]$, where the square brackets indicate "the equivalence class of ...". However, this gets tedious in the long run and just seems to use up ink while obscuring the algebraic structure of what you're doing, so it is customary to leave the brackets invisible -- and part of learning abstract algebra is to become comfortable with them being left implicit.